# How do I get the v-data-table to render icon for - and + in vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm working on my vue.js project and I'm using Vuetify.
Now, I've made a datatable like in this example from the docs:

```
https://codepen.io/pen/?&editable=true&editors=101
```

I'd like to have the same table with the - and + buttons (as you see in the code pen, around the category name).

When I inspect the code in my browser, there seems to be some kind of buttons, but they don't show the buttons in the codepen example template.

Does anyone know how to implement that?

here is the code from the codpen:

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="desserts"
      item-key="name"
      group-by="category"
      class="elevation-1"
      show-group-by
    ></v-data-table>
  </v-app>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      headers: [
        {
          text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
          align: 'left',
          value: 'name',
        },
        { text: 'Category', value: 'category' },
      ],
      desserts: [
        {
          name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
          category: 'Ice cream',
        },
        {
          name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
          category: 'Ice cream',
        },
        {
          name: 'Eclair',
          category: 'Cookie',
        },
        {
          name: 'Cupcake',
          category: 'Pastry',
        },
        {
          name: 'Gingerbread',
          category: 'Cookie',
        },
        {
          name: 'Jelly bean',
          category: 'Candy',
        },
        {
          name: 'Lollipop',
          category: 'Candy',
        },
        {
          name: 'Honeycomb',
          category: 'Toffee',
        },
        {
          name: 'Donut',
          category: 'Pastry',
        },
        {
          name: 'KitKat',
          category: 'Candy',
        },
      ],
    }
  },
})
```

My code looks like the example, except for the - and + buttons that has a wierd text instead of the icons as the example shows.

Comment: weird text instead icons points to  missing fonts - just an idea

Comment: @Estradiaz sure, but since there is no css provided in the codepen, I assume it has to do with how Vuetify work in general. But since I've copied this example into my own code, and it looks exacly like that - I don't know what happend.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the fonts - for codepen cdn is ok i guess:

[Further readings](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/quick-start#font-installation)

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      headers: [
        {
          text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
          align: 'left',
          value: 'name',
        },
        { text: 'Category', value: 'category' },
      ],
      desserts: [
        {
          name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
          category: 'Ice cream',
        },
        {
          name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
          category: 'Ice cream',
        },
        {
          name: 'Eclair',
          category: 'Cookie',
        },
        {
          name: 'Cupcake',
          category: 'Pastry',
        },
        {
          name: 'Gingerbread',
          category: 'Cookie',
        },
        {
          name: 'Jelly bean',
          category: 'Candy',
        },
        {
          name: 'Lollipop',
          category: 'Candy',
        },
        {
          name: 'Honeycomb',
          category: 'Toffee',
        },
        {
          name: 'Donut',
          category: 'Pastry',
        },
        {
          name: 'KitKat',
          category: 'Candy',
        },
      ],
    }
  },
}).$mount("#app")
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">

  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@3.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="desserts"
      item-key="name"
      group-by="category"
      class="elevation-1"
      show-group-by
    ></v-data-table>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: As I mentiond earlier, I'm working in a Vue.js project (the code pen is just for show) and I've initialized MDI Iconfont into my vuetify.js file (as the docs refer to). So, I'm still not sure why it doesen't work.

Comment: @Emilia can you check in developer tools if there is some issue pulling the CSS? As if done as in documents there should be no issue - so reduced to two reasons - either a typo or a network issue

Comment: what I can see when I inspect in developer tools, is that the materials design icons have a 200 OK status. Funny thing is that I got a icon in the same component, and that works fine... and typo, well...I guess, I'll have a look

Comment: @Emilia can you try to load icon with `v-icon` my guess here is that maybe that specific icon is missing in the source - I had this issue once switching to fontawesome